# What would be a RESTful URI for retrieving all Products created by a particular Client? (you have the client's ID)

Tags: rest

So the application is for a warehouse and you need to retrieve all of the products in the warehouse created by a particular client.  What would a URI that is RESTful look like to accomodate this?

Here are some ideas that I had:

```
/Product/Client/[the client's ID]   
/Product?clientID=[the client's ID]
```

What would a RESTful URI for this scenario look like?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of understanding, first one is better options. In first scenario, you will only check the route from the URI and client id will be in the body param. In the second scenario, you are adding clientsID in the header. Although I am not a master but what saw the way people write, they follow the first option. You might get an idea from here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Wait for the response from master in that area. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're identifying a specific client, so start with

```
/Client/[Client ID]
```

and then specify a resource "belonging to" that client

```
/Client/[Client ID]/Products
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the use case for this requirement.

If the client would usually navigate to a client, and then needs to view its products, then as @esorf said:

`/client/{clientId}/products`

*However*, if the client is displaying products for various clients (albeit only one at a time), something like this might make more sense:

`/products?clientId={clientId}`

This latter one could also be extended to use [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-2.4.2) in order display products of more than one client like so:

`/products{?clientId*}`

which expands into

`/products?clientId={clientId1}&clientId={clientId2}`